# single byte write by multiple threads in SMP without using lock

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have a multi-threaded application which has to run in SMP envirnoment, where I am writing (no read-modify-write) to single (or word-length) byte global memory from multiple threads. Can I do this without using any synchronization mechanism ( mutex, semaphore, spinlock) ?

My guesss is : Memory read/write to a aligned memory by CPU is atomic. So do not need locking for atomic access to the memory.

But there is a problem of memory ordering, i.e order of memory visibility to the CPU may not be same as the access to memory. To solve this, we need memory barrier instruction. Can we use memory barrier instructions in user space code? If not , to solve the memory ordering issue, we have to use murtex or spinlock ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GCC` provides a builtin `__sync_synchronize()` to perform a full memory barrier.

Note that some architectures (like Alpha) cannot write a single byte without performing a read/modify/write cycle at the hardware level.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As an after thought :
Since I am only writing to single global memory, is there any issue of memory re-ordering? I am not updating a complex data structure, where multiple LOAD-STORE is required.
If my understanding is correct, we do not need to use memory barrier instruction such as - __sync_synchronize (...)

Or somewhere I am going wrong ?

Comment: If you want the updated value to be seen by other cores in a timely fashion, then you need a barrier (both after the write and before the reads).  If you *don't*, then one wonders why you even need to update the global variable in the first place?